# Solving ODE via contact geometry

Tags: differential-equations, contact-geometry

I have been reading H. Geiges' "A Brief History of Contact Geometry and Topology". According to him contact transformations were introduced as a geometric tool to study systems of differential equations. I am aware that he refers to V.I. Arnold's "Geometrical Methods in the Theory of ODEs" for details, but couldn't find a satisfactory example.

I am looking for a concrete example where a contact geometric point of view helps in answering a question about an ODE.

Answer (score 9):

A comprehensive reference, with many worked-out examples, is [Contact Geometry and Nonlinear Differential Equations](https://books.google.nl/books?id=75pYPSbd4rAC&dq=Contact+Geometry+and+Nonlinear+Differential+Equations&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (2007). Here is a [review.](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jgsp/1495591266)

> Methods from contact and symplectic geometry can be used to solve
>   highly non-trivial nonlinear partial and ordinary differential
>   equations without resorting to approximate numerical methods or
>   algebraic computing software. This book explains how it's done. It
>   combines the clarity and accessibility of an advanced textbook with
>   the completeness of an encyclopedia. The basic ideas that Lie and
>   Cartan developed at the end of the nineteenth century to transform
>   solving a differential equation into a problem in geometry or algebra
>   are here reworked in a novel and modern way. Differential equations
>   are considered as a part of contact and symplectic geometry, so that
>   all the machinery of Hodge-deRham calculus can be applied. In this way
>   a wide class of equations can be tackled, including quasi-linear
>   equations and Monge-Ampere equations (which play an important role in
>   modern theoretical physics and meteorology).

The concrete application that might be what you are looking for is to the [Knizhnik–Zamolodchikov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knizhnik%E2%80%93Zamolodchikov_equations) (which models the propagation of sound beams in a non-linear medium).

Comment: This goes precisely in the direction I was hoping for. Are you aware of a self contained, short example?

Answer (score 0):

The [thesis of Raouf Dridi](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281530084_Utilization_of_Cartan%27s_equivalence_method_in_the_construction_of_an_ODE_solver) contains several worked examples of the application of Lie and Cartan's methods to ODEs.

Comment: I don't see that Dridi's approach uses contact geometry.